# Android Rom : How to test app after source code change?

Tags: android, android-source, android-build, android-rom

For testing, do you i need to make a full build every time i made changes to app source. Like I've made changes in SystemUi app. Can I run it directly on device or I need to make a full build?

Answer (score 1):

You can compile just that module like this. In root directory:

- `source build/envsetup.sh`
- Then `lunch aosp_arm-eng` (or the device you want to test it on)
- Compile your module. In your case `mma SystemUI`
- `adb install -r <<generated-SystemUI.apk>>`

For further info, check [android official site](https://source.android.com/source/building).